# Reduce space between header section and first section in Latex CV

Tags: moderncv

I would like to reduce the gap between the header section and the first section of my CV on Latex as you can see below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SSx2.png)

I am using moderncv.cls template here is the code for my main and the template :

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[top=0.2cm, bottom=0.2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\firstname{M}
\familyname{A}
\title{Chef de projet Infrastructure}
\address{Address}
\email{mail@gmail.com}
\mobile{00000}
\extrainfo{31 ans}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Formations}
\cventry{2012 -- 2015}{Cycle Ingénieur à l'ENSEIRB-MATMECA (Bordeaux)}{}{}{}{Filière Télécommunications option Génie Logiciel des Réseaux et Télécommunications}

    
\cventry{2010 -- 2012}{Classes préparatoires scientifiques }{Lycée Moulay Youssef Rabat}{}{}{MP(Mathématiques Physique)}
\cventry{2010}{Baccalauréat}{Rabat , Maroc}{}{}{Série scientifique, Spécialité Mathématiques, Mention Très bien}

\section{Éxpériences professionnelles}

\cventry{\textbf{Avril 2023 - Avril 2024}}{Freelance: Mission au sein d'EDF Renouvelables: Chef de projet IT dans le cadre du déménagement d'EDF Renouvelables vers son nouveau siège social}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}

\item Pilotage des chantiers IT et reporting COMEX/CODSIN
\item Mise en place d’une solution de réservation de bureaux et de salles de réunion

\end{itemize}

\cventry{\textbf{Février 2022 - Mars 2023}}{Rhapsodies Conseil: Mission au sein de COVEA: Chef de projet Digital Workplace}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}

\item Pilotage de projets sur le poste de travail : Migration Windows 10, Obsolescence 
\item Etude et mise en place d'une offre Smartphone-as-a-Service 

\end{itemize}

\cventry{\textbf{Aout 2021 - Février 2022}}{Magellan Consulting: Mission au sein de ENGIE: Chef de projet O365 dans le cadre d'un Carve-Out}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}

\item Définition du scope et organisation de la migration auprès des IT locaux
\item Pilotage et Reporting sur l'avancement de la migration au CTO    

\end{itemize}


\cventry{\textbf{Juin 2020 - Aout 2021}}{Magellan Consulting: Mission au sein de Technip Energies: Chef de projet IT dans le cadre du déménagement vers le nouveau siège social en construction}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}

\item Pilotage des chantiers IT et reporting au CTO 
\item Rédaction des user stories pour l'application Smartbuilding (Archibus)

\end{itemize}


\cventry{\textbf{Juillet 2018 - Juin 2020}}{Magellan Consulting: Mission au sein de SUEZ: Chef de projet Infrastructure dans le cadre du Carve-In de WTS}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}
\begin{comment}
\item Environnement international, DSI aux US, Support en Inde, 130 pays intégrés
\end{comment}
\item Mise en place de process de fourniture de services d'infrastructure
\item Pilotage des projets d’infrastructure et reporting au DSI groupe 
\item Pilotage de l'équipe support (Inde) 

\end{itemize}


\cventry{\textbf{Avril 2017 - Avril 2018}}{CGI BC: Mission au sein du groupe TOTAL: Responsable du chantier applicatif dans le cadre d'un projet de virtualisation d'applications et d'environnements de travail à destination des infogérants de TOTAL}{}{}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{3.2cm}
\begin{comment}
\item Définition du process de traitement et d'intégration des applications
\end{comment}
\item Animation d'ateliers de recueil du besoin aupprès des populations cibles 
\item Pilotage de l'intégration et des test de validation
\begin{comment}
\item Pilotage des tests de validation auprès des responsables applicatifs de TOTAL
\end{comment}
\begin{comment}
\item Support de proximité auprès des populations cibles
\end{comment}
\end{itemize}



\section{Compétences}

\cvitem{\textbf{Fonctionnel}}{Pilotage de projets (Certifié Management 3.0 Foundation),Digital Workplace, ITSM(Certifié ITIL V3 Foundation)}



\cvitem{\textbf{Langues}}{Français - \textit{Bilingue} \hspace{2cm}Anglais - \textit{Avancé: TOEIC 990/990}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}\vspace{0.1cm}      
      \hspace{3.3cm}Arabe - \textit{Langue maternelle}
      \hspace{0.6cm}Allemand - \textit{Notions}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: `\vspace{-1cm}` between `\maketitle` and `\section{Formations}` ?

Comment: It worked ! thanks :)